# Antonym: Latent

Tags: antonyms

So, I was trying to think of a word that had the opposite meaning of "latent".

Latent means "existing, yet unmanifested". I'm looking for a word that meant "existing and manifested, yet dissipating throughout his life".

For example, angry behaviour could exist in someone from an early age but then disappear over a few years... what would the adjective for that behaviour be?

Comment: Why not *dissipating*?

Comment: As usual with "what is the opposite" questions, an 'opposite' would not be well-defined here. Something that is 'not existing, yet manifested' has me beat. Something that is present but then disappears is (relatively) short-lived, ephemeral, temporary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you are seeking a word you used in your question - *[dissipating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/dissipate)*

> to disappear gradually, or to cause something to disappear gradually: *It took months of effort to dissipate the oil spill in the North Sea.*

There are numerous other terms for this gradual decline, such as

> - fading
> - extinguishing
> - exhausting
> - declining
> - diminishing
> - depleting
> - dispersing
> - diffusing
> - vanishing
> - dissolving
> - disappearing
> - devolving

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for a word that didn't end with "ing", but it looks like there aren't any.

Thanks :)

Comment: @JordanElliotFinch All of these verbs have other forms such as *faded, to extinguish, exhaust*. You can use the form that suits your structure.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at it as meaning "an existing thing that is unmanifested", then you could consider "extant" (an existing thing that *is* currently manifested) its antonym.

While perhaps not exactly what you aksed for, that word might in fact work in your case. It doesn't directly *imply* the thing has tailed off over time. However, that is the nature of things, so a hint of that implication is in there. There's nothing stopping you from helping it along a bit with other words ("still" being a good choice).

If that isn't enough for you, try "residual", which is more like "the amount that is still left after a lot has been used up". I don't think it qualifies as a proper antonym for "latent", but it may be the word you need.

Comment: That's a nice word and it fulfils half of my need, as you say. I suppose "diminishing" would fit my needs, now that I think about it.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You say *latent* means "existing, yet unmanifested", so an opposite would be ***manifest***.

*Features are divided into **latent** features and **manifest** features*.

***Manifest*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/manifest)

> (adj.) Clear or obvious to the eye or mind.
>   *"her manifest charm and proven ability"*

Answer (score 2):

The most frequently used antonymn of "latent" is "patent".   Lawyers use it commonly, and it means "obvious".  Latent's most common usage is closest to "hidden"--like a latent fingerprint.  It is there, but you can't see it until you do something, like dust it with powder.

Nonetheless, I don't think "patent" is appropriate for what you're trying to convey.  You may wish to consider "diminishes" or "becomes less frequent or less intense over time".

Answer (score 0):

***Waning***, from *[wane](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waning)*, To decrease gradually in size, amount, intensity, or degree; decline.